# Keyboard hides Textfield even if resizeToAvoidBottomInset is true

Tags: flutter, keyboard, overflow, textfield

Unfortunately the Keyboard hides the TextField if it gets opened.

I also tried `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`, but it remains causing Render OverFlow error.

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: getPrimaryDarkColor(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: -10,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/login_path_background.png",
                width: 350,
                color: getPrimaryColor().withOpacity(0.4),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: share the complete code snippet>?

Comment: could you please include full sample code, so we can regenerate issue?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the body in a `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Column in a SizedBox with device height as it’s height and the device width as it’s width. Then, inside that SizedBox, wrap the Column with a SingleChildScrollView. I had this same exact issue and just using a SingleChildScrollView does not work because the Stack item has no specific size or position. When you wrap the whole SingleChildScrollView in a SizedBox with the device size it works. Hope this helps!